# Use of vectorized plotting arguments for 'pch' when plotting a 'stripchart' by factor in R

Tags: r, vector, plot

I often like to specify plotting arguments like `pch` or `col` by creating a vector whose values correspond to some aspect of all the individual data points. This strategy doesn't seem to work however, when the data are plotted by factor, because the plot argument will be assigned by giving the first value of the vector to the first group, the second value to the second group, and so on, rather than by giving the first value to the first point, etc.

Here is an example of what I would like to be able to do. For instance, let's say I want to make a stripchart of petal length, grouped by iris species, but also specify that specimens with a certain petal length should have a different plotting symbol.

```
data("iris")

pch <- rep(16, length(iris$Petal.Length))
pch[which(iris$Petal.Length < 0.4 )] <- 17

stripchart(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, 
       vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter", 
       pch = pch)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer:

This is not do-able with `stripchart`.

You would need to make the plot "by hand" in order to use `pch` the way you want.

#### Longer Answer:

The source code for the `stripchart` has the following (where ... means I left out some code):

```
n <- length(groups)
...
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
...
points(..., pch = pch[(i - 1L)%%length(pch) + 1L]
```

We see that the `pch` argument is assigned a scalar value based on `i`. So, essentially, it only allows for `pch` to be used to specify a plotting symbol by group and cannot be used to specify a symbol by point, the way you want it to.

Note that this is behavior specific to `stripchart` and not necessary to all plotting functions in R where plotting is done by factor.

#### As an Aside:

In your code above, your condition is never true:

```
which(iris$Petal.Length < 0.4)
integer(0)
```

So even if `stripchart` allowed `pch` the way you want it to, your code wouldn't quite do the trick.  You need `< 5` or something rather than `< 0.4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subset arguments, the right way is

```
data("iris")
stripchart(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, subset = Petal.Length > 1.4,
   vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter", ylim = c(1,7),
   pch = 16)
stripchart(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, subset = Petal.Length < 1.4,
   vertical = TRUE, method = "jitter", add = TRUE,
   pch = 17)
```